# Loop through [[String: Any]]

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

With

```
let posts = json["posts"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
print(posts)
```

I get

```
[["id": 1, "title": title 1], ["id": 2, "title": title 2], ["id": 3, "title": title 3], ["id": 4, "title": title 4], ["id": 5, "title": title 5]]
```

How can I loop through this to get value of each `id` and `title`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through `posts` with a `for-loop` and make sure you have a value with `guard`.

```
for post in posts{
    guard let id = post["id"] as? Int,
          let title = post["title"] as? String else { continue }
}
```